# Databricks Delta Lake - Reading data from JSON file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake

I'm currently learning Databricks and using a combination of Python (pyspark) and SQL for data transformations.

As of now I have a json file in the following format:

```
{
    "issuccess": true,
    "jobProcess": "usersList",
    "data": {
        "members": [
            {
                "id": "bot1",     
                "name": "databot",
                "active": true,
                "profile": {
                    "title": "Test Bot",
                    "phone": "1234"
                 },
                 "is_mailbox_active": true
             },
             {
                ....
             }
         ]
     }
}
```

I'm able to dump this data into a temp view via. following Python (PySpark) logic:

```
 usersData = spark \
                .read \
                .option("multiLine", True) \
                .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE") \
                .json("C:\\Test\data.json") \
                .createOrReplaceTempView("vw_TestView")
```

With above, the vw_TestView data is in **struct<members:array<struct<....** format.

| Column | DataType |
| --- | --- |
| issuccess | boolean |
| jobProcess | string |
| data | struct<members:array<struct<id:string, ....> |

As an output, I need to select/display data only from **members** of **'data'** column array in a proper format.

Performing a **select * from**  will expectedly return 'results too large....' error.
Also, since I need to eventually select specific content from **'data'** column how can I construct a proper select query for this above view.

The select query output must look something as below:

| id | name | profile |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bot1 | databot | { "title": "Test Bot","phone": "1234"} |
| bot2 | userbot | { "title": "User Bot","phone": "7890"} |

How can this be achieved?

I tried performing

```
%sql
select data.members.* from vw_TestView
```

but this is not supported for **'data.members'** column's data type and errors out with following message:

```
Can only star expand struct data types.  ..........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `members` is an array.  In this case you need to do that via following operations:

1. Select `members` field using `select("members")`
2. Explode the `members` field using the `explode` function ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/explode.html))
3. extract data from the underlying structs

Something like this:

```sql
select col.* from (select explode(data.members) as col from vw_TestView)
```

P.S. All of this could be done directly via PySpark as well.

Comment: Using explode(data.memebers) is correct BUT,
 it won't give the result in the format I posted in the question. Basically, doing so will give us all result in one single row, instead of breakdown of data in columns.

Comment: can you try updated answer? I missed the target structure. It works

Comment: Ah!! Yes, this works like a charm.
I was so close with getting this exact SQL but didn't get it quite right as you did here.